# How to use the LLVM IR API

Tags: c++, llvm

I have just finished building LLVM with `ninja`, `clang-cl` and `cmake`, and I was wondering how do I can get this working so I can include LLVM headers and libraries in my C++ visual studio project. I want to do something similar to what [Kaleidoscope](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/index.html) does, the tutorial by LLVM.

I am just wondering how I can compile my project using llvm headers and libraries. Should I copy the llvm build into the project so the headers work? Should I shange the project settings to include libs/dlls that are required? How should I do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is too broad to be answered on Stack Overflow. Any answer would be comparable to the tutorial in terms of length. Please follow the tutorial and come back with specific problem if you have any.

Comment: I just changed it to be more narrow.

Comment: http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html

Comment: I already built it though

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!
First I rebuilt with visual studio (release x64). Then I used cmake to generate .sln filed for project (instead of trying to use llvm-config). The important part was to set LLVM_DIR to the right location, for me this was `llvm-project\llvm\cmake\modules`.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.3)
project(SimpleProject)

set(LLVM_DIR C:\\...\\llvm-project\\llvm\\cmake\\modules)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

message(STATUS "Found LLVM ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_DIR}")

include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable(test test.cpp)

llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs support core irreader)

target_link_libraries(test ${llvm_libs})
```